# How to make editable WebView on a UITableViewCell?

Tags: html, uitableview, webview

How can I load local HTML contents to a WebView on UITableViewCell which can be editable too, Such as the mail body of the apple example of the [MailComposer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MailComposer/Introduction/Intro.html). Here we also can get copy paste and magnifier facilities. Please help me with suggestion or with sample codes. I am warned already to be fired by my company. Please please help me.

Comment: So you want the user to be able to edit what is displayed in the UIWebView?  Do they edit the HTML markup code directly, or are they supposed to have WYSIWYG editing ability?  Or is the HTML something really simple, like pure text?

Comment: @aroth thank you very much. Yes the user to be able to edit what is displayed in the UIWebView. But the display may contain rich texts, I mean colored text with different font size and family. It may also include gif animated images. On the the example of apple MailComposer it is absolutely possible. But unfortunately core code is not available.

Answer (score 0):

With the following assumptions:

1. Users do not need advanced editing features (images, bulleted lists, WYSIWYG anything).
2. Users do not edit HTML markup.
3. The HTML only includes text and basic formatting like linebreaks and indents.

I would suggest:

1. Maintain two versions of your HTML content, one that displays in the `UIWebView` and on that the user can edit.  The editable one should have all markup tags stripped and, where sensible, replaced with their corresponding plaintext character(s) (so for instance, replace `<br>` with `\n`).
2. Load the HTML version of the content into your table as normal (I assume you are already doing this).
3. When you table goes into editing more, replace (or overlay) the `UIWebView` with an editable `UITextView` populated with your non-HTML version of the content.
4. When the user indicates they are done editing, take the edited version of the text and invert the replacements you did in step #1 (so for instance, replace every `\n` with `<br>`).
5. Load the modified string you got in step #4 into the UIWebView.  Optionally save it to file if you want the app to remember/retain a persistent history of edits to the field.

Although, if the company you are working at thinks that the way to motivate engineers is to threaten them with termination, really you should just thank them for their inept management techniques and be on your way.

Comment: thanks for your nice and tricky suggestion. I needn't to edit markup but need allow clients to edit the displayed contents. Actually I need to make a mail client where client could be send mail with rich text, gif emoticons and banner as well by using their own mail settings.